# where in the sources of Wireshark I can see the calls to the pcap?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap

I want to find the place in the code where Wireshark takes the packets that arrive to the driver.

I guess this is done using `libpcap` or some other API for capturing packet.
I looked at the source code but I didn't find any call to any function from `libpcap`.

So I am searching for the place where Wireshark communicates with the `pcap` interface or the driver directly. I want to know what functions are called (especially for Linux).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Most of the calls are in dumpcap.c, capture-pcap-util-unix.c, capture-pcap-util.c, and capture-wpcap.c.